# How to call others method in same the class ,python3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, methods, self

I try to use class for coding , i do this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class MainWin:    
    def __init__(self, win, *args):
        self.win=win
        self.Reg=win 
    def First(self):
        self.Reg.title("1111111111 ")
        self.Reg.geometry("400x200+400+120")
        self.Bt=Button(self.Reg, text="Ok", command= self.Second)
        self.Bt.pack()      
    def Second(self):
        self.win.title(" 2222222222 ")
        self.win.geometry("700x400+400+150")
        self.win.resizable(0,0)
def main():
    master=Tk()
    App=MainWin(master)
    App.First()
    master.mainloop()    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run it give me the first window with it's "Bt" Button , when press this button it call the 2nd method and give the 2nd window , All is well , but the button of 1st window will viewing in the second window , why?
please, I need help

Comment: You don't have 2 windows; self.win and self.Reg are the same window. The second method is just resizing it and repositioning it. To remove the button add the command `self.Bt.destroy()` to the Second method.

Comment: Oh , Thanks bro. Can you tell me : How to make the 2nd method as a new window? Please.

Comment: To open a second window that shows at the same time as your first window use the Toplevel class. To "switch" windows (close one and open another) you are doing it the right way. We don't actually close the window, we just reconfigure it.